# Select2 do not highlight an option when not hovering over select box

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using Select2 and I am adding a custom button to the start of it using the following code:

```
$("#select2-ddlCustomer-container").off().on('click',
  function() {
    $("#ddlCustomer-add").remove();
    $("#select2-ddlCustomer-results")
      .before("<div id='ddlCustomer-add'><i class='fas fa-user-plus'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Create new customer</div> ")
      .promise().done(function() {
        $("#ddlCustomer-add").off().on('click',
          function() {
            alert('test');
          });
      });
  });
```

However as soon as the select box opens it automatically highlights the first option even though I have not hovered over it, this means that when I hover over my "Create new customer" button the first option in the list is also highlighted which looks confusing to the end user.

Does anyone know how I can stop it highlighting an option by default and only highlight an option if the mouse is actually hovered over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got around this issue by adding the following code to remove the highlight class from all the options when I hover over my "Create new" button, this doesn't technically unselect the option and it doesn't resolve the issue with the first option in the list being highlighted when the dropdown is opened even though I haven't hovered over it but it is a workable solution for now:

```
$("#ddlCustomer-add").hover(function () {

        // Un-highlight all options
        $('.select2-results__option').removeClass('select2-results__option--highlighted');

});
```